# not able to remove css border for last child

Tags: css, sass

I could not able to remove border for the last child of li after. Last child after which is not working. Let me know how to resolve this issue.

```
.main-menu__link {
        font-size: 15px;
        background: #fff;
        color: #f37321;
          &::after {
          border-right:#522e91 1px solid;
         height: 14px;
         content: " ";
         padding-left: 15px;
         &:last-child() {
          border-right: none;
        }
                 }

<ul class="main-menu">
<li class="main-menu__item"><a class="main-menu__link" href="#">PRESS RELEASE</a></li>
<li class="main-menu__item"><a class="main-menu__link" href="#">REQUEST A REP</a></li>
<li class="main-menu__item"><a class="main-menu__link" href="#">PRESCRIBING INFORMATION </a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you update the SASS? You're missing a brace or two

Comment: I missed to paste the brace in the above code.My code editor i didn't missed the brace. I need to how to remove the border for the last child of ::after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're selecting the last child of `main-menu__link` inside a `main-menu__item`, which is itself.
You have to select the last child of `main-menu__item` first.

add this to your styles:

```
.main-menu__item {
  &:last-child {
    .main-menu__link {
      &::after {
        border: none;
      }
    }
  }
}
```